Evaluating a function definition with `C-M-x` versus using a hook
The below functions enable the use of eglot in org jupyter src blocks (after https://github.com/joaotavora/eglot/issues/216#issuecomment-1051931693)
(defun org-babel-edit-prep:jupyter-python (babel-info)
  (setq-local buffer-file-name (expand-file-name (->> babel-info caddr (alist-get :tangle))))
  (eglot-ensure))
(defun mb/org-babel-edit:jupyter-python ()
    (interactive)
    (org-babel-tangle '(4))
    (org-edit-special))

Opening an org file and executing the functions in the scratch buffer, works like a charm, but I would like to use this approach in my init file. In my naive approach, I figured I place the functions on a hook like this:
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'org-babel-edit-prep:jupyter-python)
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'mb/org-babel-edit:jupyter-python)

Alas, this is not the same as using C-M-x and does not work. Worse, it screws up fontlocking.

It turns out that it is unnecessary to adapt the original solution (see link in OP) to jupyter-python src blocks since setting:
(setq org-babel-jupyter-override-src-block "python")

will treat a python src block similar to a jupyter-python src block. So the following will start eglot as expected when editing python-src blocks even so we use the jupyter-python backend.
(setq org-babel-jupyter-override-src-block "python")
(defun org-babel-edit-prep:python (babel-info)
    (setq-local buffer-file-name (expand-file-name (->> babel-info caddr (alist-get :tangle))))
    (eglot-ensure))
(defun mb/org-babel-edit:python ()
      (interactive)
      (org-babel-tangle '(4))
      (org-edit-special))



Adding an undefined function to a hook doesn't define the function. If you need to evaluate a function definition in *scratch*, to get it defined, then you need to evaluate it somewhere, from your init file.
If it's defined in some library, then require that library in your init file. If not, put the code that defines it in your init file.
Putting a function on org-mode-hook just tells Org mode to invoke that function when the mode is turned on. It doesn't define that function.

Thanks for the explanation. Placing the two functions as is into my init file, was indeed my first approach. However, this results in an error when calling org-edit-special. At the same time, using the same function in the scratch buffer works without issue. So it has to do with when the functions are defined. I also tried loading the functions after org or eglot with:
eval-after-load but no luck

Post a different question for the error you get. Show the actual error message there, or (better) a backtrace (non-nil debug-on-error). A wild guess is that the code needs lexical-binding and your init file doesn't have that. But you don't show enough code here to know what the problem is. Clearly you're using one or more packages, for which we'd have to guess. Questions should ideally post a recipe to repro the problem, starting with emacs -Q (no init file).

understood, but no easy feat... however in my quest to simplify the problem, I did find a working solution, see below
